# The word for how real a fictional world seems to be?

Tags: vocabulary

A few weeks ago my old English Teacher updated his word of the week and I can't remember the word only the definition; It was something along the lines of

> 'How real A fictional world or character feels to be .'
>   If Anyon

Comment: I'm guessing it wasn't "realistic".

Comment: Duplicate of: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/28307 https://english.stackexchange.com/a/397561 https://english.stackexchange.com/a/220847

Answer (score 1):

**verisimilitude**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/verisimilitude)

the quality of appearing to be true or real;
something that has the appearance of being true or real;
likelihood